# AngularJS Controller submit form

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have a problem with a controller

```
 .factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth){
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();
  return auth;
 })

.controller('authCtrl', function() {
  var authCtrl = this;

  authCtrl.user = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  console.log('hoi1');

  authCtrl.login = function (){
    console.log('hoi2');
  };
});
```

-

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal" ng-controller="authCtrl">
<div class="modal-background"></div>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form ng-submit="authCtrl.login()">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <p id="loginError">&nbsp;</p>
      <input type="email" name="loginEmail" value="" placeholder="email" class="input" ng-model="authCtrl.user.email">
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="loginPassword" value="" placeholder="******" class="input" ng-model="password" ng-model="authCtrl.user.password">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The controller is always in my body, but I see `hoi1` in the console, but when I submit the form, I don't get `hoi2`

What's wrong?

Sincerely,
Jur

Comment: Try `ng-controller="authCtrl as authCtrl"`. @HARI's answer works but isn't best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal" ng-controller="authCtrl">
```

to

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal" 
ng-controller="authCtrl as authCtrl">
```

If you want to use `controller` **`this`** then you have to add `ng-controller` as `ng-controller="authCtrl as authCtrl"`

Check this [tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) for more info on Controller as

[Working Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/wvoenn3z/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this one works with my options. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Use $scope in your controller

```
.controller('authCtrl', function( $scope) {
   $scope.user = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
   };

   console.log('hoi1');

   $scope.login = function (){
    console.log('hoi2');
   };
});
```

Comment: `$scope.login = function(){console.log('hoi');}` 
`<form ng-submit="login()">`

works, but why itsn't with `authCtrl`

Comment: you can look the following link which is briefly explained why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 1):

It is because when your $scope execute in controller to view, it execute console.log('hoi1') as it do not wait for any event to happen. You just write "debugger;" in your code and need to check its execution part